# HOw to get hold of return value when using dapper to execute

Tags: dapper

HOw would I make the above code return bool based on the execution. So i can return to the calling method.

```
public void UpdateSpanStartDate(SpanRecord spanRecord)
{
    Run(conn => conn.Execute("[dbo].[SpecailSpanStartUpdate]",
        new DynamicParameters(new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
             {"SpanId", spanRecord.SpanId},
        }), null,Config.CommandTimeout, CommandType.StoredProcedure));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That depends entirely on where the `bool` is meant to be coming from. The most common setup would be for the sproc to `select` some kind out output; if this is the case, the most appropriate thing to do is to use `Query<T>` along with a LINQ operation such as `Single`. For example (also tidying up the parameters):

```
Run(conn => conn.Query<int>("[dbo].[SpecailSpanStartUpdate]",
    new {spanRecord.SpanId}, null,
     Config.CommandTimeout, CommandType.StoredProcedure).Single() != 0);
```

Here I'm expecting a single row that has an `int` in the first column, returning `true` if the `int` is non-zero.

Comment: okay so i guess instead of execute i can use query so i can get the value back if insert, update or delete was successful. I was looking at the execute method as NonExecuteQuery.

Comment: @user then use Execute. The return value from Execute is the same as from ExecuteNonQuery